# What is the difference between java-openjdk and java-latest-openjdk?

Tags: fedora, java, openjdk

I was looking at the packages available for Java on Fedora and saw this:

`java-openjdk` is version 12.0.0.33-4
`java-latest-openjdk` is version 12.0.2.9-1

It's obvious that "latest" is the most recent version. But what is the difference otherwise? Both are on a rolling release. Is the latest package just bleeding-edge with more potential bugs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `java-openjdk-12.0.0.33-4` doesn't contain any files and has `java-latest-openjdk` as dependency. It's a package renaming thing.

[https://fedora.pkgs.org/30/fedora-updates-x86_64/java-openjdk-12.0.0.33-4.rolling.fc30.x86_64.rpm.html](https://fedora.pkgs.org/30/fedora-updates-x86_64/java-openjdk-12.0.0.33-4.rolling.fc30.x86_64.rpm.html#howto)

> **Changelog**
>   2019-04-26 - Petra Mikova  - 1:12.0.0.33-4.rolling
>   - the package is now completely emptied, only requires java-latest-openjdk
>   - this has to happen due to the conflict of this package with other java packages
>   - the package is being renamed to java-latest-openjdk
>   - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1693987